# ASP.Net DropDownList will not redirect to new value

Tags: c#, asp.net, redirect, drop-down-menu

I have an ASP.Net DropDownList that will never keep its new value if it get its value when the page loaded. For instance, if I select a value and click a button Response.Redirect fires and redirects me back to the same form, but at a URL with a routing value from the DropDownList. This is what it should do.

The problem is if I select a new value and click the button again, the new selectedvalue is not used when redirecting. It uses the old one instead.

The code for the DropDownList is:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="stateDropDownList" runat="server" DataSourceID="statesSqlDataSource" DataTextField="state" DataValueField="state" AppendDataBoundItems="true" CssClass="searchddl" OnPreRender="stateDropDownList_PreRender">
                 <asp:ListItem Value="0" Text="Select State"></asp:ListItem</asp:DropDownList>

            <asp:SqlDataSource ID="statesSqlDataSource" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:myConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT DISTINCT state FROM Decertified ORDER BY state"></asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Then in my .cs page I have a button click event that includes:

```
        if (stateDropDownList.SelectedIndex != 0)
        {
            string stateddlvalue = stateDropDownList.SelectedValue.ToString().ToLower().Replace(" ", "-");
            redirecturl += "state/" + stateddlvalue + "/";
        }
```

Like I said before this redirects just fine if I click the button after selecting from the DropDownList when the page load the first time, but if I load a page at http://example.com/decertified/state/michigan and select Kansas from the dropdownlist the page redirects to Michigan again instead of Kansas.

It seems like even thought I changed the visible value on the DropDownList on the page that the Selected Value is still what it was when it loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it, turns out had code that set the SelectedValue for the DropDownList in both the DropDownList_PreRender and the Page_Load. I removed the code from the Page_Load and it started working right.

Lesson: set the SelectedValue like this:

```
    {
        if (IsPostBack == false)
        {
            if (RouteData.Values["state"] != null)
            {
                TextInfo stateti = new CultureInfo("en-US", true).TextInfo;
                string xstate = RouteData.Values["state"].ToString().Replace("-", " ");
                xstate = stateti.ToTitleCase(xstate);
                stateDropDownList.SelectedValue = xstate;
            }
        }
    }
```